# Why is f=O(g) if f(n) grows more slowly than g(n)?

Tags: algorithm, math, asymptotic-complexity

If a function `f(n)` grows more slowly than a function `g(n)`, why is `f(n) = O(g(n))`?

e.g. if `f(n)` is `4n^4` and `g(n)` is `log(4n^n^4)`

My book says `f=O(g(n))` because `g=n^4*log(4n)=n^4(logn + log4)=O(n^4*logn)`. I understand why `g=O(n^4*logn)`, but I'm not sure how they reached the conclusion that `f=O(g(n))` from big `O` of `g`.

I understand that `f(n)` grows more slowly than `g(n)` just by thinking about the graphs, but I'm having trouble understanding asymptotic behavior and why `f=O(g(n))` in general.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a plain English explanation of "Big O" notation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487258/what-is-a-plain-english-explanation-of-big-o-notation)

Comment: There is no asymptotic notation in the standard definition of big O.

Comment: The function f(n) that you picked isn't O(g(n)). Did you write them backwards?

Comment: @templatetypedef Just updated with new example, thanks!

Comment: You might also want to look up the Omega and Theta classes that cover slower and equivalent growth. In your question you had probably Theta-like behavior in mind.

Answer (score 2):

The formal definition of big-O notation is that

> f(n) = O(g(n)) if there are constants n<sub>0</sub> and c such that for any n ≥ n<sub>0</sub>, we have f(n) ≤ c · g(n).

In other words, f(n) = O(g(n)) if for sufficiently large values of n, the value of f(n) is upper-bounded by some constant multiple of g(n).

Notice that this just says that f(n) is *upper-bounded* by g(n), not that f(n)'s rate of growth is the same as g(n)'s rate of growth. In that sense, you can think of f(n) = O(g(n)) as akin to saying something like "f ≤ g," that f doesn't grow faster than g, leaving open the possibility that g grows a lot faster than f does.